# Downloading a html file from wwwroot keeps showing Not Found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to download a .html file that I placed in the wwwroot.

This is the function:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    var file = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"EmailTemplate","base.html");
    var x = System.IO.File.Exists(file);
    var result = File(file, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    return result;
}
```

I tried to check if the file exists but it returns false. The file variable shows the path to the file which is:

> wwwroot\EmailTemplate\base.html

I'm unsure of what else I need to do.

EDIT:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(
    new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "EmailTemplate")),
        RequestPath = "/EmailTemplate"
    }
);
```

This is what I added to my Startup.cs

Comment: Make sure you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your `Configure` method in the `Startup` file. In your controllers you can inject an `IHostingEnvironment` interface and use it to retrieve your `wwwroot` path like : `_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you set yours as the answer? It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your `Configure` method in the `Startup` file.

In your controllers you can inject an `IHostingEnvironment` interface and use it to retrieve your `wwwroot` path like:

```
_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
```